# jqgrid subgrid edit-dialog 'submit' and 'cancel' buttons disappearing off form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a grid employing subgrids in ASP.net MVC jqgrid. When I expand a subgrid and use the add or edit modal dialog box for that subgrid, everytime I change to a new field in the form, the 'submit' and 'cancel' buttons get pushed off the bottom of the form. Moving the form brings those buttons back. I've pretty much copied the Trirand subgrid demo. The only difference I can see is that I have an edittype of TextArea for one of the fields. Anyone else run into this problem (and if so, how did you fix it)?

**Edit:** This problem occurs when your add/edit dialog is too small to contain all the form elements. Both width and height must be sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue, try changing the height attribute of the edit/add dialog.

```
jQuery("#specialItemGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", { height: 370, reloadAfterSubmit: true, addCaption: "Special Item", bSubmit: "Add to Order" });
```

Comment: Thanks. For anyone using the MVC version it's `myJQGrid.AddDialogSettings.Height = myHeightInt;`